# Pain in knee joint

Tags: pain, knee

*when I kneel down, I feel an inner pain in my knee joint. I can not feel this pain while walking or riding stairs. Only when my knee joint touches floor or anything,then I can feel that pain. Please let me know any home method to cure this pain.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying cold compresses to the painful knee is one of the best and easiest ways to reduce pain and swelling. The cold will constrict the blood vessels, reducing blood flow to the affected area and thus reducing swelling. It will also give you relief from the pain.

1. Wrap a handful of ice cubes in a thin towel.
2. Apply the compress to the affected knee area for 10 to 20 minutes.
3. Do this two or three times daily until your pain is gone.
   A bag of frozen peas also works well as a cold compress. You can opt for alternating hot and cold compresses as well for chronic pains.

http://www.top10homeremedies.com/home-remedies/home-remedies-knee-pain.html

http://everydayroots.com/arthritis-remedies

http://www.healthline.com/health/pain-relief/knee-pain-home-remedies

Comment: There are cheap "cold packs" which you can put in the freezer, have straps to go around your knee or ankle, and their outside material is such that doesn't give you a cold "shock", i.e. it's a bit insulating.